# PIC 32 two I²C slave address

Tags: microcontroller, pic, i2c

I'm developing for a PIC32 platform. My application consists to realise I²C communication between µC 8051 and PIC32. The 8051 is the master and the PIC32 is the slave. I have established I²C communication between the two microcontrollers. My need is to affect 2 slave addresses to the PIC32. Also I have succeeded to affect 2 addresses to the PIC32 using this code:

```
I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS=0x40;
I2CSetSlaveAddress(I2C4, I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS>>1, 0x10, I2C_USE_7BIT_ADDRESS);
```

So the pic32 can accept data from 8051 through the 0x60 and 0x40 address. Now I want to determine which parameter in I²C protocol allow me to determine when data arrives from 0x60 and when from 0x40 because I have two different types of data to receive in the PIC32.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I don't find any information in the datasheet of I2C which mentions the control of the interface that receive data.In another mean, which control let me know if the slave use the 0x60 or 0x40 to receive data because i need to filter data according to the interface(0x60 or 0x40). For example using a line code like this : If (datafrom(0x60)) do ... else (datafrom(0x40)) do. I want to know the parameter datafrom.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Youpiiiiiii.
I find answer to my question. It's throw this code line
if (I2C4STATbits.S && !I2C4STATbits.R_W && !I2C4STATbits.D_A && I2C4STATbits.RBF)
    {
     //   State1
     //   Master write, last byte was address.
     i2cAddressByte = I2C4RCV;
}
According to the value of i2cAddressByte I can say if the data is comming from 0x60 or Ox40.

Comment: Yes, this is the low-level version of the code above...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PIC32 family data sheet chapter 24](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61116E.pdf). There the process of address detection is explained. It also shows (even though its not explictely mentioned in the text) that the address is in the I2C receive register after a valid address has been detected.

The code above looks like you are using the PIC32 peripheral library that comes with xc32. Look at the supplied manual there (hlpI2C.chm). It contains a chapter 'Operating as an I2C slave', which has the sample code you are looking for:

```
if (I2CReceivedDataIsAvailable(I2C1))
{
    slaveRxData = I2CGetByte(I2C1);
    if (I2CReceivedByteIsAnAddress(I2C1))
    {
        // Handle address byte
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle a slave RX byte of data
    }
}

if (I2CTransmitterIsReady(I2C1) && more_data_to_send)
{
    result = I2CSendByte(I2C1, slaveTxData);
    // Handle sending a slave TX byte of data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I don't find any information in the datasheet of I2C which mentions the control of the interface that receive data.In another mean, which control let me know if the slave use the 0x60 or 0x40 to receive data because i need to filter data according to the interface(0x60 or 0x40). For example using a line code like this : If (datafrom(0x60)) do ... else (datafrom(0x40)) do. I want to know the parameter datafrom.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation I mentioned? Or at the code I pasted in? When a slave address is detected, the address is in the 'received byte' register. This is the 'slaveRxData' field in the code I copied in. So you just need to check whether slaveRxData is 0x60 or 0x40.

Comment: Also, the main data sheet doesn't explain I2C in detail, one needs to look at the individual chapter. Unfortunately, the I2C chapter (Ch. 23) is not linked from the Microchip pages (at least not for the PIC32s I looked at). But Google gave me the link above, so you need to look at that. (And yes, it mentions where the slave address is stored)